# Is there a test class specific listener ( similar to Junit runner ) in TestNG?

Tags: junit, testng

Existing Junit setup :

I have written a junit test runner which parses the test class before its execution and  reads custom annotations written on each testable method in the test class .Based upon the aggregated value of the annotations formulate a configuration which i then use to setup the test environment and manipulate it . When the tests are executed based upon the manipulation done on the test environment i generate the result .

Current State :

Now we are evaluating TestNg for the same task .I understand the terminologies and ways of execution are bit different in TestNG . Now i have different suites file for various suites in TestNG , each of the suite has a test section with multiple test classes inside it . I wanted what i did for Junit (as mentioned above) in TestNG also , hence when the suites execute and each test class is executed then just before execution of the test class i want to perform my environment setup and manipulation .I saw the documentation for various listeners in TestNG and haven't been able to find the specific listener for my purpose (capable of intercepting individual class execution ). Is that a listener for doing what i need Or is there a way to achieve what i want to do ?

I am not looking to execute my test setup programatically and want to evaluate the capabilities of TestNg  hence please provide answer for what i seek for rather than condemning the approach itself .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you post an example of what a test class looks like, the custom annotations you use and explain what they do?

Based on your description, an `IMethodInterceptor` might be what you need (TestNG gives you a list of the methods it's about to run and you get a chance to alter that list).

Comment: `@RunWith(MyRunner.class)
@MyClassAnnotation(artifcats = {"TestApp.war"},config = "myconfigfile")
public class MyTestClass {
    
    @Test
    @MyMethodAnnotation(url = "/TestApp/test.myservlet",load = 10)
    public void testServletAutoDiscovery() {
        //get response for the load generated and test for the valid response values
    }
}`

My class annotation configures a container based upon the values provided , my method annotation generated the load for the artifact deployed .The test class can contain several of such test methods who depend on same config file .

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution that i am looking for . Seems the functionality that i am looking for is provided by implementing interface ITestRunnerFactory whose newTestRunner method returns me a Test runner .